# Django Google App Engine Server Error 500

Tags: mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mariadb

I have deployed my Django app to Google Cloud. It worked fine when I hosted it locally and throughout the steps outlined in [this post](https://medium.com/@BennettGarner/deploying-a-django-application-to-google-app-engine-f9c91a30bd35).

It raises a server Error(500) when I try to view the live link.

When I enable Debug in the settings.py, this is the full traceback. (Torque is the name of my project), and showroom is my app.

The traceback refers to a views attribute (num_manufactureres) which I never had a problem with when hosting it locally.

```
OperationalError at /showroom/
(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://torque-256805.appspot.com/showroom/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
Exception Location: /env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__, line 166
Python Executable:  /env/bin/python3.7
Python Version: 3.7.4
Python Path:    
['/srv',
 '/env/bin',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 24 Oct 2019 09:45:29 +0300
...

/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py in __init__
        super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2) …
▶ Local vars
...

    num_manufacturers = Manufacturer.objects.all().count() …
▶ Local vars
```

I'm new to Google Cloud, so I don't know how to start debugging this.

Here are some possible issues:

1. The server instance I created on the cloud.google.com uses europe-west3 as a region. But when I was deploying, I thought that it created a completely new server and chose  europe-west6 as a better option. (Close proximity, better reliability etc...)
2. I changed my project settings.py for better security according to the `check --deploy` Django command.

Otherwise, I can't think of anything else. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi @Rene, have you seen this [Django example from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#understanding_the_code)? it will explain you how to deploy your Django app and SQL database to App Engine. If you look at the `settings.py` file, this is the unix socket that you may need for your HOST paramater `/cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>` when running App Engine on production. Last but not least, make sure you have `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['localhost']` if `HOST='localhost'`, or else you can just use `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'`, as example above. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @sllopis You won't believe what I did. I had written the databases into the ```settings.py``` during development, but before deploying I overwrote (not replaced! ) this file with an earlier 'vanilla' settings file. I couldn't troubleshoot it because it was such a silly mistake.

Comment: Please create an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: I posted a rather generic answer for this issue. @Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this **[Django example on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#understanding_the_code)** `settings.py` file:

```
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/[YOUR-CONNECTION-NAME]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
        }
    }
```

Last but not least, if you're running your app locally, make sure you have `ALLOWED_HOSTS= ['localhost']` if your database host is `HOST='localhost'`, or else you can just use `'HOST': '127.0.0.1'`, as shown in the code sample above.

Comment: Thanks for your simple answer. A silly error can cause so much heartache.